# Why can't puppet start the dropbox daemon?

Tags: ubuntu, dropbox, puppet

I'm using the Dropbox [command-line utility/daemon](http://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx) on Ubuntu 11.10 but it's not working with Puppet.

I can successfully control dropbox manually:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/dropbox [status/start/stop/status]
```

However when I configure Puppet to ensure that dropbox is always running, it fails with this log message:

```
(/Stage[main]/Dropbox::Service/Service[dropbox]/ensure) change from stopped to running failed: Could not start Service[dropbox]: Execution of '/etc/init.d/dropbox start' returned 1:  at /etc/puppet/modules/dropbox/manifests/init.pp:8
```

Here is my puppet manifest file:

```
class dropbox {
  include dropbox::service
}

class dropbox::service {
  service { "dropbox":
    ensure => running,
  }
}
```

The above error message also seems to imply that the dropbox "status" command isn't working for Puppet because I get the same error message ("Could not start") even when Dropbox is already running.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I see that you also posted this on the puppet users group but I'll give this a shot. When the dropbox service is in its `running` state, do a `ps -ef | grep dropbox` and see what that returns. I've run into similar issues in the past and it seems that puppet doesn't like when the _daemon_ name (the name that shows up in `ps -ef`) is different from the name you supplied (i.e "dropbox"). This is a longshot but can you give that a try?

Comment: Hi @MarvinPinto, yeah I couldn't quite get to the bottom of it so I thought I'd check here too. Here's the output from the ps statement: dropbox  14544 1 10 11:45 ? 00:00:01 /home/dropbox/.dropbox-dist/dropbox

Comment: Could you try to add hasstatus => true to service statement? What's output of sudo /etc/init.d/dropbox status; echo $?

Comment: Hey @kupson, I'll try adding hasstatus. That command returned dropboxd for USER dropbox: running (pid 9823)
0

Comment: @richardkmiller So that rc.d script has working status command - you definitely should put hasstatus => true in puppet manifest. That "Can not start..." error should disappear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puppet versions before 2.7 by default don't use /etc/init.d/service status command. They look for process name in process table, so if the daemon process name is different from service name those behaviour will give you errors like:

```
 ...Service[dropbox]/ensure) change from stopped to running failed...
```

on every execution of puppet agent. You should check if that service has working status command:

```
 sudo /etc/init.d/dropbox status; echo $?
 # That command should return output with "running" text and return code 0 like:
 dropboxd for USER dropbox: running (pid 9823)
 0
```

Then tell the puppet to use it instead of it's own (<2.7) mechanisms - put "hasstatus => true," in service definition.

Answer (score 1):

To add to this as it's a popular Google hit for "puppet can't start service", I had a similar problem on CentOS. Turns out that my problem was due to **sudo**: I had

```
Defaults requiretty
```

in my **sudoers** file. Changing this to

```
Defaults requiretty
Defaults:root !requiretty
```

Fixed the problem, and allowed my service script (which was using sudo to run the daemon) to work via puppet.

Hope this helps future Googlers!